# attaching __call__ at runtime not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to define the `__call__` dunder method at runtime, but with no success. The code is the following:

```
class Struct:
    pass

result=Struct()
dictionary={'a':5,'b':7}
for k,v in dictionary.items():
    setattr(result,k,v)

result.__call__=lambda self: 2
```

However, the interpreter returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Struct' object is not callable
```

But, if I add the dunder method since the beginning, all magically works:

```
class Foo():
   def __call__(self):
      return 42

foo=Foo()
foo() #returns 42
```

I'm using Python 3.4 on windows 64bit machine.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you do `obj(...)`, Python executes `obj.__class__.__call__(obj, ...)`

Comment: For reference, see [Special method names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=special%20methods#special-method-names): "if a class defines a method named __getitem__(), and x is an instance of this class, then x[i] is roughly equivalent to type(x).__getitem__(x, i)."

Comment: And more generally for all special methods, [Special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup): "implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in the object’s instance dictionary."

Comment: @ShadowRanger,  thanks for the link about the special method lookup; reading it improved my knowledge about special methods;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited**

You can attach `__call__` by adding it to the **class** object:

```
Struct.__call__ = lambda self: 2
```

But if you want to get different values per instance you should:

```
class Struct:
    def __call__(self):
        return self._call_ret

result=Struct()
dictionary={'a':5,'b':7}
for k,v in dictionary.items():
    setattr(result,k,v)
    result._call_ret = 2

print(result())
```

@Blckknght thanks.

Comment: There's no need for `setattr` if the name is a constant. You can just do `Struct.__call__ = lambda self: 2` and `result._call_ret = 2`

Comment: At the end I used the method proposed by kAlmAcetA. However, the link [special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup) got from ShadowRanger really solved why I encoutered this problem.